# Is it possible call a procedure using strings?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central

I need to call a lot of procedures with incrementing names. Is it possible to generate the name of a procedure in a string and then call it using that string? Python has its own `exec` method which would be ideal but I'd be fine if I could dynamically pick the name of a function.

**Edit:**
To elaborate on what this is for, I have to write a performance test that repeats procedures of multiple codeunits. Depending on the parameters given, I could have 100 codeunits containing 30 procedures each, so to call all of them I currently have to explicitly call each and every one of them.

```
startTime := Time();
progressDialog.Update(1,'Proc0A');
for i := 1 to 1000 do begin
  Set0_No0.Proc0A(1);
  progressDialog.Update(2,i);
end;
timeElapsed := Time() - startTime;
if timeElapsed = 0 then begin
  timeElapsed := 1;
end;
baseTime := timeElapsed;

FinishTest(timeElapsed, baseTime, 0, false, false, 1, 1, 1000);

startTime := Time();
progressDialog.Update(1,'Proc0B');
for i := 1 to 1000 do begin
  Set0_No0.Proc0B(1);
  progressDialog.Update(2,i);
end;
timeElapsed := Time() - startTime;
if timeElapsed = 0 then begin
  timeElapsed := 1;
end;

FinishTest(timeElapsed, baseTime, 0, true, false, 1, 1, 1000);
```

Instead, I'd like it to work like this:

```
procedure CallMethod(setNo:Integer; codeunitNo:Integer; procedureNo:Integer; type:Code[5]; repetitions:Integer)
begin
  for i := 1 to repetitions do begin
    Exec('Set%1_No%2.Proc%3%4(1)',setNo,codeunitNo,procedureNo,type);
    Set0_No0.Proc0A(1);
    progressDialog.Update(2,i);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Could you supply some sample code of what you have or what you are trying to achieve? It would give a better idea of which solution to suggest.

Comment: @kaspermoerch I've added some more clarification in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you require is not available in AL.

There are however a couple of options you could consider:

1. Using a combination of `enums`, `interfaces` and `codeunits` you can remove a lot of boilerplate code.
2. Using a script (e.g. PowerShell) you could parse all your source files, find the codeunits and their procedures and then generate a new codeunit that invokes each procedure.

Comment: I figured it wasn't possible. I had done it using typescript to generate the `.al` file before, but I was wondering if AL might possess a feature like that.

Comment: Not at the momemt unfortunately. However the AL language has improved a lot over the past couple of years with regards to dynamic programming.